# using cookies to save firebase token

Tags: firebase, next.js

I've been following along with this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBGAdenirbs
but one thing comes to mind is the safety of storing a firebase token in a cookie ?
Couldn't anyone just use that token and keep hitting firebase.

```
  const handleUser = async (user) => {
    if (!user) {
      nookies.set(undefined, "token", "");
      return;
    }
    const token = await user.getIdToken();
    setUser(user);
    nookies.set(undefined, "token", token);
    setLoading(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onIdTokenChanged(getAuth(), handleUser);
    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

The above code is a hook that just watches for changes on onIdTokenChanged handler and sets cookies on the front end with the token from firbase.

Anyone know if this is safe and if not what could I do to make it safer for production.